# Alfa awus036h wireless adapter acting strange

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, alfa-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I recently got an alfa awus036h and plugged it in. whenever I go to network settings it keeps connecting and disconnecting repetitively. the light on the adapter also flashes every time it connects.
I installed the drivers from realtek's website and it still does the same. does anyone know what I should do to fix this problem? I've done a lot of research on google and couldn't find a thing useful, thanks

Comment: Try using a different cable to connect with.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For 14.04, try this solution :
Edit with admin right file /ect/rc.local and add those 3 lines :

iwconfig wlan1 rate 36M auto

iwconfig wlan1 frag 512

iwconfig wlan1 rts 512
Save and eventually reboot